# Creating a Segue from UIButton in .xib file to a ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

In the app I am building, I am looking to present a map of a user's area to them with certain landmarks identified with custom markers. When the user taps a marker, an Info Window appears with some basic information and a button that reads "Get more info". The goal is for when a user clicks that button, they are taken to a new ViewController.

What I am finding, however, is that there is no built in way to segue off of a UIView. I have created a Protocol/Delegate on the UIView class but cannot seem to actually get the views to change. Below is my code:

**UIView.swift (the controller for the Info Window)**

```
import UIKit

protocol MapMarkerDelegate: class {
    func didTapInfoButton(data: NSDictionary)
}

protocol MoreButtonTapped: class {
    func didClickMoreButton(name: String)
}



class MapMarkerWindow: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var openField: UILabel!

    var secondDelegate: MoreButtonTapped!
    weak var delegate: MapMarkerDelegate?
    var spotData: NSDictionary?


    @IBAction func didTapInfoButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapInfoButton(data: spotData!)
    }

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "MapMarkerWindowView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    }

    @IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if(secondDelegate != nil) {
            self.secondDelegate.didClickMoreButton(name: nameField.text!)
        }
        print("Info Button Tapped for \(nameField.text!)")
    }


    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "displayLocaleData" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! InfoViewController

            destinationVC.selectedBarName.text = nameField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the receiving VC:

```
import UIKit

class InfoViewController: UIViewController, MoreButtonTapped {




    @IBOutlet weak var selectedBarName: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var selectedBarData: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Assign delegate to self
        //        MapMarkerWindow.delegate = self
        selectedBarName.text = selectedBarName.text
    }

    func didClickMoreButton(name: String) {
        print("Success")
    }


}
```

I am not receiving any errors with this code. If I attempt to add MapMarkerWindow.delegate = self, I receive an error because a UIView does not have that ability. Any thoughts or workarounds would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1- This should be inside the vc that contains the custom nib view ( suppose it's `CustomViewController` )

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "displayLocaleData" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! InfoViewController  
        destinationVC.selectedItemName.text = nameField.text!
    }
}
```

2- When you instanite an instance of `MapMarkerWindow` , you need to set the delegate to that `CustomViewController`

```
let windoinfo = /// 
windowInfo.delegate = self
```

3- Adopt the delegate here

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, MoreButtonTapped {

   func didClickMoreButton(name: String) {
      print("Success")
      // here do self.performSegue.....
   } 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! However, the custom nib is a UIView class. Should I be creating it as a UIViewController instead?